# How do you load data into a PySpark dataframe from a JDBC source only once?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am new to PySpark and I am having some difficulty that I am hoping someone can help with.

I am using PySpark within a Jupyter Notebook. I set up my spark session and then I load data using JDBC with a query to Teradata.

```
TD_df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url",teradata_conn)
.option("user",user_name)
.option("password",user_password)
.option("driver", td_driver)
.option("query","""select * from monthlysamples sample 100""")
.load
```

Using `TD_df.printSchema()` I get what I expect. `TD_df.count()` confirms there are 100 records. In one cell of my notebook, I will be doing some analysis (sums, averages, etc). Then I will want to create a histogram in a cell and then a pie chart in another. This is when I noticed each time I run a cell, the data loaded into the dataframe is refreshed. This behavior means my analysis looks incohesive. I assume there is a way to stop this refreshing of the dataframe however I have been unable figure it out.

I assume it is something simple so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would need to cache your dataframe once it's loaded. you can do it using `TD_df.cache()`

Comment: Do I need to release the cache before stopping the spark session?

Comment: No you don't need to, but if you want you can call `df.unpersist()`

Comment: when you run a single cell the previously assigned variables from different cells should remain unchanged. This is how notebooks are usually used. Are you sure you are only executing the cell that uses dataframe's data and not the one that loads the data?